# Error submitting request for facebook publish_action permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, publish-actions

I have created a Facebook App from Facebook Developers account and using that app to do offline wall posting. I learnt that it requires publish_action permission for which a report needs to be submitted to Facebook. I have filled all the data but it does not allow me to submit the form and shows "**It looks like you haven't made any API requests to access content with the publish_actions permission in the last 30 days**" message on the publish_action permission. **Can anyone please find me a good solution to be able to submit the form for review?**